# Access windows forms function from WPF windw

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i am trying to call a function in Form1 from WPF window and i am getting the following error

"Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

also getting the same error when trying to access the Public variables in Form1 from wpf window.

is it not possiable to do it?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Are the methods/variables instance or static? Do you have an instance?

Comment: i want to use the WebBrowser control in windows forms since the wpf browser control doesnt have HTML element, so i use the broswer control to click a button then get the link

Comment: i am not sure what are  instance or static

Comment: but suppose i want to get the public value x from Form1, i would say Form1.x, this is all i am trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to the MSDN [this error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwhc0d0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), this is a problem with trying to reference instance variables as if they are static.

If your class is `Form1`, you cannot access methods or variables that are not static by calling `Form1.Method()`. This won't work ever, not just in WPF. This is pretty basic stuff, you might want to read up more on VB. Check out [Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx) and [Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8%28v=vs.110%29) documentation.

To access, for example, the method `Show()` on Form1, you must [instantiate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx) (create an instance of an object), and call the method on your object. Like this.

```
Dim frm As New Form1()
frm.Show()
```

Comment: so when i do                                          'form1.Timer1.Start() i get the same error although form1.show() is working fine